# How to rescale range of numbers shifting the centre in spark/scala?

Tags: function, apache-spark, machine-learning, logarithm

Which function in spark can transform / rescale values in range `-infinity` to `+infinity` or `-2` to `130` etc to max value to be defined.

In below example, I want to ensure that 55 is 100, and 100+ is 0

`before |  after`

`45-55 | 90-100`

`35-44  | 80-89`

`...`

`100+ or < 0| 0-5`

is any of the [ML features functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html) useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it, thanks @user6910411 for your help.
You can use dense or sparse vector depending on data and replace `MinMaxScaler` with `MaxAbsScaler` and extract values using `linalg.Vectors` or `DenseVector`
Idea is to split data at the point of required median and reverse scale for one half, then scale both halfs and merge DF.

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Normalizer
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.MaxAbsScaler
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.MinMaxScaler
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val vectorToColumn = udf{ (x: DenseVector, index: Int) => x(index) }

val gt50 = df.filter("score >= 55").select('id,('score * -1).as("score"))
val lt50 = df.filter("score < 55")

val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
.setInputCols(Array("score"))
.setOutputCol("features")

val ass_lt50 = assembler.transform(lt50)
val ass_gt50 = assembler.transform(gt50)

val scaler = new MinMaxScaler()
.setInputCol("features")
.setOutputCol("featuresScaled")
.setMax(100)
.setMin(0)

val feat_lt50 = scaler.fit(ass_lt50).transform(ass_lt50).drop('score)
val feat_gt50 = scaler.fit(ass_gt50).transform(ass_gt50).drop('score)

val scaled_lt50 = feat_lt50.select('id,round(
vectorToColumn(col("featuresScaled"),lit(0))).as("scaled_score"))

val scaled_gt50 = feat_gt50.select('id,round(
vectorToColumn(col("featuresScaled"),lit(0))).as("scaled_score"))

val scaled = scaled_lt50.unionAll(scaled_gt50)
```